# Problems with web.xml

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7, web.xml, jdbcrealm

first of all i want to apologize for my bad English. Ok, i have a problem. I am building application that uses jdbcrealm and web.xml for security. Login is done by web form. Application is running on Apache Tomcat 7 and i am using Primefaces 4.0. In web.xml I have defined some roles and some security constraints. When I log in into application httpservlet request.login(username,password) do the job fine, and request.isUserInrole("role") also do do job, Faces.getExternalContext.redirect redirects page to correct folder on which security constraint is applied, in browser I see correct URL .....but the page is Blank!!! If I check page source I see page source of login page.....I will put some screen shots bellow. Please help me...I am trying solve problem for 2 weeks now!

/*

*/
**this is web.xml**

```
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>

    <param-value>afterdark</param-value>

</context-param>

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping> 

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-role>
    <description>Administrator A</description>
    <role-name>1</role-name>
</security-role>
 <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Administrator A</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Administratorske datoteke</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/a1/*</url-pattern> --> 
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>        
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Administrator A</description>
        <role-name>1</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


    <login-config>

    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/prijava.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/pogreska.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>prijava.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

****this is login page(prijava.xhtml)****

```
        <div class="slika_za_prijavu">

        <h:outputLink id="loginLink" value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PF('prozor_za_unos').show()" title="prijava">   
            <p:graphicImage value="/slike/prijava.png" /> 

        </h:outputLink>

        </div>           

        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />  

        <p:dialog id="prozor_za_prijavu" header="Prijava" widgetVar="prozor_za_unos" resizable="false">  

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputLabel for="k_ime" value="Korisničko ime:" />  
        <p:inputText value="#{provjera_prijave.k_ime}"   
                id="k_ime" required="true" label="korisnicko_ime"   
                requiredMessage="Potrebno je upisati korisničko ime!"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="zaporka" value="Zaporka:" />  
        <h:inputSecret value="#{provjera_prijave.zaporka}"   
                id="zaporka" required="true" label="zaporka"
                requiredMessage="Potrebno je upisati zaporku!"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">  
            <p:commandButton id="gumb_za_prijavu" value="Prijavi se" update="growl"   
                             actionListener="#{provjera_prijave.prijava(actionEvent)}"   
                oncomplete="obrada_zahtjeva_za_prijavu(xhr, status, args)"/>  
        </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>  

        </p:dialog>  
    </h:form>
```

**this is login controller (provjera_prijave)**

public void prijava(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

```
    FacesMessage poruka = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest zahtjev = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {
        String pocetna_stranica;            
        zahtjev.login(k_ime, zaporka);
        HttpSession sesija = zahtjev.getSession();
        if (!sesija.isNew()) {
            sesija.invalidate();
            sesija = zahtjev.getSession();                                
        }
        if (zahtjev.isUserInRole("1")) {
            sesija.setAttribute("trenutni_korisnik",k_ime);
            pocetna_stranica = "/a1/pocetna_a1.xhtml";
            poruka = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Dobro došao", k_ime);
            try {
                fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
                fc.getExternalContext().redirect(zahtjev.getContextPath()+pocetna_stranica);

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("UPOZORENJE!", "Pogreška u izvođenju programa. Nije moguće preusmjeriti stranicu."));
            }
        } 
        else if (zahtjev.isUserInRole("2")) {
```

**and this is url which is in my browser when user with role "1" log in. Before this goes localhost and port...ERMP is the neme of application....**

"ERMP/a1/pocetna_a1.xhtml"

here is blank page with page source of login page

I hope that question is understandable. 
When comment web resource in web.xml everything works
Please help!!Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use the tomcat's built in ([Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html)) authentication and authorization, there's a couple of things you should attend to.

First, your login form needs to be something like this:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="Login"/>
    <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
```

You could use primefaces components to preserve the layout. In that case you will need to do some "javascripting" in order to define the action of the form rednered by the JSF **h:form** component.
    
        
        
        ...

```
<script>
jQuery("#form").submit(function() {
  jQuery(this).attr("action", "j_security_check");
  jQuery(loginVar.jqId).attr("name", "j_username");
  ....
});
</script>
```

The second detail is that you won't need to worry about the login part as described in your login controller. Once you send j_username and j_password to j_security_check, everything will run just fine.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to go on desired page, which is improvement but i can only do that with one user...if i define welcome page for user with role "1" i can see the page but user with role "2" cant see the page....do you know how to define multiple welcome pages in web.xml?